# Remove parent DIV

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div class="action">
   some_text
   <a class="delete_action" name="q1">some</a>
</div>
<div class="action">
   some_text
   <a class="delete_action" name="q2">some</a>
</div>
```

And jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('.delete_action').click(function(event) {
       $.get('/delete_action?name=' + event.target.name, function(data) {
       });

       // how can I remove parent DIV element (*)

       return false;
    });
} );
```

When the user click the link, the code makes ajax-request which removes the data in the database. In addition I want to remove parent DIV element from DOM tree. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would use

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('.delete_action').click(function(event) {
       var $this = $(this);
       $.get('/delete_action?name=' + event.target.name, function(data) {
            $this.parent().remove();
       });

       // OR
       //$this.parent().remove();

       return false;
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.delete_action').click(function(event) {
   $.get('/delete_action?name=' + event.target.name, function(data) {});
   $(this).parent().remove();
   return false;
});
```